# Не отнимается число

Tags: php

Делаю баланс пользователя на `PHP` (баланс не может быть меньше нуля).
Допустим, пополняю баланс на 10 рублей и покупаю товар за 10 рублей. Оплата проходит, а баланс становится 0. Но, когда я пополняю баланс на 8 рублей и покупаю товар за 8 рублей (цена товаров хранится в базе данных), то оплата не происходит, ошибки в `PHP` логе нет. В чем может быть проблема?
На всякий случай код баланса:

```
if ($id && $job_user) {
  $job->balance = $job_user->balance - abs($this->GetWeight($packing[$id_product])) * $num_packing[$id_product];
  $this->users->update_job($id_user, $id_product, $job);
```

Так же хочется отметить, что происходит оплата любой суммы, кроме числа 8.

Comment: Как проверяли гипотезу про 8? Все остальные параметры выдерживали одинаковыми? В любом случае без кода методов update_job, GetWeight, balance  что либо определенное сказать невозможно

Comment: у меня есть выпадающий список с суммами от 1 до 10, так вот со всеми проходит оплата, а с восьмеркой нет. Я считаю, если бы была ошибка в коде, тогда и другие не считались бы.

Comment: Ну не думаете же вы, что отыскали фундаментальную проблему вселенной, заключенную в в цифре 8? Конечно в коде, в чем же еще.

Comment: @JohnDoe, а со списком все хорошо?

Comment: @JohnDoe Ну и код списка проверить бы

Comment: Плюсую к версии со списком. Возможно, в вариант с числом 8 попал лишний пробел или что-то вроде этого.

Comment: и да, имена методов класса принято начинать со строчной буквы, а не с заглавной. getWeight(), а не GetWeight()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в типе данных в БД. Данные были в типе float(5,2), они просто-напросто не вмещались по расчетам.